# Azure Active Directory authentication with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm a bit new to react native and I've been looking at this [package](https://github.com/shedaltd/react-native-azure-ad-2) to try to set up some basic active directory authentication:

I've installed the package:

```
npm install -s react-native-azure-ad-2
```

And used the example provided at the end of the page

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, View} from 'react-native';
import {AzureInstance, AzureLoginView} from './azure';

// CONSTANT
const CREDENTIAILS = {
    client_id: 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    client_secret: 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    redirect_uri: 'xxxx',
    scope: 'User.ReadBasic.All Mail.Read offline_access'
};

export default class azureAuth extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.azureInstance = new AzureInstance(CREDENTIAILS);
        this._onLoginSuccess = this._onLoginSuccess.bind(this);
        this._onLoginCancel = this._onLoginCancel.bind(this);
    }

    _onLoginSuccess(){
        this.azureInstance.getUserInfo().then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    _onLoginCancel(){
        // Show cancel message
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AzureLoginView
                azureInstance={this.azureInstance}
                loadingMessage="Requesting access token"
                onSuccess={this._onLoginSuccess}
                onCancel={this._onLoginCancel}
            />
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('azureAuth', () => azureAuth);
```

I changed `import {AzureInstance, AzureLoginView} from './azure';` to `import {AzureInstance, AzureLoginView} from 'react-native-azure-ad-2'`. Then changed the `client_id` and `client_secret` with the ones from Azure Directory.

Now when I try to compile I get the follwing error:

```
"Invariant Violation. WebView has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from 'react-native-webview' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview"
```

This error is located at line `<AzureLoginView` ... inside the `return`.

I installed the package using `npm i react-native-webview` but the error persisted.

How can I fix this? Are there other packages that are easy to implement AD auth in React Native?

Comment: Why dont you just use ADAL?

Comment: @Alex mind if you share a link and a guide? many thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/psignoret/50e88652ae5cb6cc157c09857e3ba87f

Comment: Try googling vanilla js ADAL or something like that

Comment: @Alex doesn't seem very intuitive to use.

Comment: It is a vanilla JS implementation of Azure AD Auth. Pretty much all AD Auth packages you use will be built up from this. If you are able to work this out you should then be able to work out your issues with the package you are using